# Could you please help me analyze the structure of this sentence?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, sentence

"The ideas of unilinear development, in this perspective, is one-sided, because it fails to account for the whole range of possibility in which process constitutes but one of several dominant configurations." I am not sure what is the meaning of "but" in "but one of several dominant configurations. "  Does this word "but" mean "except?"

Comment: Means *surprisingly only* one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means "only". This is the adverb "but" ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/but_3)).

> (OALD) There were a lot of famous people there: Lady Gaga and Hugh Jackman, to name but two.